# Replacing columns names using a data frame in r

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have the matrix

```
m <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE,dimnames = list(c("s1", "s2", "s3"),c("tom", "dick","bob")))

   tom dick bob
s1   1    2   3
s2   4    5   6
s3   7    8   9

#and the data frame

current<-c("tom", "dick","harry","bob")
replacement<-c("x","y","z","b")
df<-data.frame(current,replacement)

  current replacement
1     tom           x
2    dick           y
3   harry           z
4     bob           b

#I need to replace the existing names i.e. df$current with df$replacement if 
#colnames(m) are equal to df$current thereby producing the following matrix


m <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE,dimnames = list(c("s1", "s2", "s3"),c("x", "y","b")))

   x y b
s1 1 2 3
s2 4 5 6
s3 7 8 9
```

Any advice? Should I use an 'if' loop? Thanks.

Comment: +1, nice question with example code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `which` to match the `colnames` from `m` with the values in `df$current`. Then, when you have the indices, you can subset the replacement colnames from `df$replacement`.

```
colnames(m) = df$replacement[which(df$current %in% colnames(m))]
```

In the above:

1. `%in%` tests for `TRUE` or `FALSE` for any matches between the objects being compared.
2. `which(df$current %in% colnames(m))` identifies the indexes (in this case, the row numbers) of the matched names.
3. `df$replacement[...]` is the basic way to subset the column `df$replacement` returning only the rows matched with step 2.

Comment: Could you provide a little more explanation as to how this one liner works? This would make it more readable for beginning R users.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra, added an explanation--not sure if it is the best. Please feel free to improve upon it or offer suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

A slightly more direct way to find the indices is to use `match`:

```
> id <- match(colnames(m), df$current)
> id
[1] 1 2 4
> colnames(m) <- df$replacement[id]
> m
   x y b
s1 1 2 3
s2 4 5 6
s3 7 8 9
```

As discussed below `%in%` is generally more intuitive to use and the difference in efficiency is marginal unless the sets are relatively large, e.g.

```
> n <- 50000 # size of full vector
> m <- 10000 # size of subset
> query <- paste("A", sort(sample(1:n, m)))
> names <- paste("A", 1:n)
> all.equal(which(names %in% query), match(query, names))
[1] TRUE
> library(rbenchmark)
> benchmark(which(names %in% query))
                     test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1 which(names %in% query)          100   0.267        1     0.268        0          0         0
> benchmark(match(query, names))
                 test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1 match(query, names)          100   0.172        1     0.172        0          0         0
```

Comment: +1 -- `%in%` and `match` are very similar. My preference is usually for `which` and `%in%` because it's easier for me to remember, since it reads something like: "Which of *these values* (`df$current`) is **in** *these other values* (`colnames(m)`." With `match` I always have the tendency to use the same format and end up with `NA`s. I don't know if there are any performance issues either way though.

Comment: You're right, `%in%` is more intuitive and therefore better to use in general, `?match` gives more information on the pros and cons. For the geeks amongst us I'll add some timings!